# How to unit test that the application of Spring AOP advice is as expected?

Tags: java, unit-testing, aop, spring-aop

We are working on a large team with many off-shore resources, most of whom are at a junior-level and we do not expect to fully understand how to use Spring AOP. Despite that, we still want to use Spring AOP because of rapidly changing (by our customer) nature of the applications cross-cutting concerns.

Our concern is ensuring that the advice is being applied how we expect it is, meaning:

1. ensuring that it is getting applied to the methods we want it to get applied to
2. that it is not getting applied to any other methods

What worries us most is that the juniors could make changes that could break our point cuts by doing things like renaming methods. Also, we are worried about which advice gets applied where because some services on exception should rollback the transaction, while some should log and carry-on, which we want to implement using AOP as well.

Therefore we want to programmatically test the application of Spring AOP advice, but we are not sure how to best proceed.

**tl;dr:** How to unit test the application the application of Spring AOP advice?

---

**PS**- please no semantic complaints of the use of "unit" vs "integration" test here.

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with is a Spring unit test, and create mock implementations of all the services (targetted and not), and have them injected into the unit test, and then have the services the advice calls into mocked as well, and then call each method on each service and then verify whether or not the advice's mocked service was called. For every. single. method. on every. single. service. :-S

*Hopefully*, there is some higher-level facility where you could query into Spring to ask where it gets applied, but we have not uncovered any such ability in any of the tutorials so-far.